# mongo-express | Could not connect to database using connectionString: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/"

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, yaml, mongo-express

When trying to spin up a docker container with docker-compose,
I  get the following error message:

```
 (node:8) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: Current Server Discovery 

and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
mongo-express    | Could not connect to database using connectionString: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/"
```

I noticed that mongo-express always adds a double quote to the end of my connection string, is this intentional or did I mess something up in my docker-compose file?

The file:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
    mongodb:
        image: mongo:latest
        container_name: mongodb
        restart: unless-stopped
        networks:
            - backbone
        expose:
            - 27017
        ports:
            - 27017:27017
        env_file:
            - ./.env
        command: [--auth]
        environment:
            - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=${DB_USERNAME}
            - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
        volumes:
            - ./data:/data/db

    mongo-express:
        image: mongo-express
        container_name: mongo-express
        restart: unless-stopped
        networks:
            - backbone
        ports:
            - 8081:8081
        environment:
            - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=127.0.0.1
            - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL="mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017"
            - ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_USERNAME=${DB_USERNAME}
            - ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}

networks:
    backbone:
        driver: bridge
```

I already tried updating my version of docker/docker-compose and mongodb.

How do I resolve the error?
Or is there a workaround I could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a container, `localhost` refers to the container itself. So when Mongo Express tries to connect to the database at `localhost`, it looks for the database inside the Mongo Express container.

Docker compose let's you refer to containers using their container names, so you should change your Mongo Express environment variables to

```
    - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodb
    - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL="mongodb://mongodb:27017"
```

Comment: The container stopped crashing now, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with the help of Hans Kilian but i have to add one enviroment variable that looks to be required, this is my docker-compose file.

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo:4.4
    container_name: mongodb
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root   # Root username access: Yes i sure.
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123456 # Root password now required: Yes i will try this password.
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - ./mongo_data:/data/db

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    container_name: mongodb_web_client
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ENABLE_ADMIN: true # (WAIT) Access as root: Yes like the other container.
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: root # Root username: Like the previous
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: 123456 # Root password: Like the previous
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER: mongodb
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL: mongodb://mongodb:27017/
    depends_on:
      - mongo
```